# button click not responding in Django

Tags: python, django

Hi I am new to django.

I want a button in my webpage to change the text.

however it does not happen
.
i am unable to understand what to change it does not give any error either

```
my html page
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>The current time</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>My helpful timestamp site</h1>
<p>It is now {{ current_date }}.</p>

<form action="#" method="GET">
<p>It is {{ result }}</p>
<input type="text" name="q">
<input type="submit"  name="summary">
</form>
<hr>
<p></p>
</body>
</html>
```

my views.py file

```
import textwrap
import json,httplib
import datetime
from django.template.loader import get_template
from django.template import Context
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.generic.base import View
from django.shortcuts import render


def HomePageView(request):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    t = get_template('index.html')
    html = t.render(Context({'current_date': now}))
    return HttpResponse(html)

def getJson(request):
 if(request.GET.get('summary')):
  html = t.render(Context({'result': 'this'}))
 return HttpResponse(index.html)
```

my urls.py file

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from People.views import HomePageView
from People.views import getJson


urlpatterns = patterns(
'',

url(r'^', HomePageView),
url(r'^', getJson),
)
```

Comment: You have two views with the same URL pattern. How are you expecting that to work?

Comment: what should i change in this?

Comment: Give the second one a different URL, and make the form submit to that URL.

Comment: Change form's method to "POST"

Answer (score 0):

You need to post your form to the JSON view.

form;

```
<form action="{% url 'json_view' %}" method="POST">
    <p>It is {{ result }}</p>
    <input type="text" name="q">
    <input type="submit"  name="summary">
</form>
```

views.py file

```
def HomePageView(request):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    t = get_template('index.html')
    html = t.render(Context({'current_date': now}))
    return HttpResponse(html)

def getJson(request):
    t = get_template('index.html')
    if 'summary' in request.POST:
        html = t.render(Context({'result': 'this'}))
        return HttpResponse(html)
    return HttpResponse(index.html)
```

urls.py file

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    url(r'^', HomePageView, name='home'),
    url(r'^json/$', getJson, name='json_view'),
)
```

Comment: @TusharSaha what's wrong with it & have you tried to post the form, as that'd be better practice.

Answer (score 0):

i solved this by adding this code in urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from People.views import HomePageView
from People.views import getJson
from People import views

urlpatterns = patterns(
'',

url(r'^$', views.HomePageView ),
url(r'^getJson/$', views.getJson, name = 'getJson'),
```

)